# QGIS Simple fill symbology for vector layer not exporting to pdf

Tags: qgis, symbology, pdf, vector-layer

I'm trying to use simple fill i.e. Diagonal X, on vector layers, the layers look fine on the composer when zoomed out (for example to a scale of 1:6,000) however when I export to pdf the distance between the lines decreases to the extent it is difficult to see the pattern. I have been using the line pattern fill to create my own Diagonal X symbology which with a large enough distance between the lines is fine.

There are a number of us using a wide range of symbols daily.

Is a quick way of fixing this for all symbols possible?

I've tried changing the units to pixels, mm or map units which I've seen mentioned a few times and this is not making a difference

Comment: What are the settings you are using for the fill? And what happens in the composer if you look at the layout at a 1:1 scale?

Comment: I've left the settings as the default when choosing Diagonal X under simple fill (border - solid line, join style - bevel, border width 0.26, offset x,y - both 0.00). I've also tried using the JNCC phase 1 habitat survey key which I've downloaded as a .xml file, and have had the same issue. Using symbology I have created layering line pattern fill and simple fill this has not been an issue, the fill pattern exported to pdf is the same as what is shown in composer.  I'd rather not remake all the JNCC standard patterns if there is a simple fix. Thanks!

Comment: and seen in a 1:1 scale in composer it is dense hatching, much denser than when viewed at a scale of 1:11,000, but still not as dense as it comes out on pdf (so dense the lines are difficult to distinguish)